# django 1.7 how to add foreign key constraint on django session model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

In Django 1.7 adding a foreign key constraint on Django session gives,

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1215, 'Cannot add foreign key constraint')
```

below is my model definition

```
class UserSession(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,blank=True,null=True,default=None)
    session = models.ForeignKey('Session')
```

After looking into the database, django_session table doesn't have an id column. I have also tried adding `db_column='session_key'` (considering session_key is primary key in django_session table) parameter to ForeignKey() function. I am still getting the same error.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It has to do with the collation of your database. You need to ensure that the collation of the database is the same as that one of the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved the problem to_field attribute for specifying which column to refer.

```
class UserSession(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User,blank=True,null=True,default=None)
        session = models.ForeignKey(Session,to_field='session_key',related_name='+')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
class UserSession(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,blank=True,null=True,default=None)
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it gives the same integrityError.